# What is the preferred way to toggle fullscreen vs fullscreen with panels on iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, controls, ipad, gestures, fullscreen

I have a full screen iPad app that deals with graphics. The user has full screen as canvas, with extra controls added along the bottom and right side of the screen.

**I'm looking for an intuitive way for the user to hide these extra panels and view full screen.** Ideally, the user can easily switch between full screen and screen with panels.

I see that the native iOS camera app uses a single tap gesture to toggle panels on and off - touch anywhere but the panels does show/hide transition.

Because my app deals with graphics, and the user is expected to touch the screen quite a lot, **I'm thinking of using double tap gesture to show/hide full screen.** Would double tap to hide be counter-intuitive to users who might've been used to a single tap?

I can do the same show/hide with buttons, but this poses a question - once the panel is hidden, do I keep buttons on the screen (as little tabs), or hide them somehow?

Native iPhone camera hides top status bar, top navigation bar and bottom toolbar with a single tap gesture:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Camera Roll user does not interact with the main view in other ways than swipe (to change image) and tap (to show/hide controls). If in your case user needs to interact with the displayed elements, I would suggest following a great example of Adobe Ideas, where the toolbar is minimized to a very small tab visible in a corner of the screen, activated by tapping or swiping:

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a fantastic design, my app designer suggested something similar, but I didn't get it until seeing your screenshots. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Double tapping the screen seems like a decent idea - an alternative, if your application does not have a semantic use for swiping up/down, is to use a large swipe to scroll the canvas and then reveal your menus.  Another idea is show a small button at the top of the screen that the user can pull down or tap to reveal menus (swipe down on the iPhone home screen to show what I mean).

Answer (score 1):

Taking a clue from the desktop and some other iOS apps I've used along what you describe.

1. Switching between full-screen and non-, use a single button - look at the QT player and Mountain Lion apps (Safari).
2. When you switch to full-screen mode on the desktop you can hover over the header area to make the menu and toolbars appear again - for your app you may want to consider a "pull tab" that will optionally show/hide the full menu (look at XCode storyboards and the ability to expand/collapse the view drawer.

So, putting it all together and wrapping up. Maybe the enter/exit full-screen mode button is in the navigation bar - when you are *not* in full screen mode another "tools drawer" icon appears to display the various menu items. When you are out of full-screen mode, the tools drawer is just always there.

Another option would be to just always be in full-screen mode, then have the show/hide on the tools panel itself - see the Apple Pages app for iOS for an example.

As to the double-tap - on a mobile platform, double-tapping is not a standard concept yet. I actually don't know of any native app which requires it - and I don't believe any of the apps I use regularly have it either. It would require educating the user on this bit of knowledge, which may not be worthwhile if you can get around just not using double-tap at all.

Comment: Good point, I've removed the double tap and went with a persistent semitransparent button which does fullscreen toggle